# SimpleCmsImage.save will not save a thumbnail image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tinymce

I have a Ruby on Rails web application that uses the Simple CMS plug-in to upload images to the app.

I've used this before.  In fact, my current web application is a clone of an original application that works perfectly.

With the new app, the image itself uploads okay, but - unlike the original app - it does not automatically generate a thumbnail image.

I've isolated this down to the point where SimpleCmsImage.save is called.  In the original app, this automatically does two insertions into the simple_cms_image table - one for the image itself; and one for the automatically-generated thumbnail image.

In the new app, there is only one insertion for the image, none for the thumbnail.

Does anyone have any suggestions?  I'm at my wit's end to figure this one out?

Thanks in advance,
Tim